# .realm file automatically backed up by iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, realm

my app was rejected because of the size of the content that it uploads to iCloud. The only file in my app's Documents folder is the *default.realm* database file. I think that this is the file that iCloud is uploading. How can I prevent iCloud to upload the database to iCloud?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [App Backup Best Practices section of the iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW17), `<Application_Data>/Library/Caches` or `<Application_Data>/tmp` will not backup to iCloud. Generally, you can use `<Application_Data>/Library/Caches` directory to save your data that you won't backup to iCloud.

To change the file path of Realm, you can pass the `path` parameter when creating Realm instance, like below:

```
let realmPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.CachesDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
let realm = Realm(path: realmPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("data.realm"))
```

Otherwise, you can use `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` file system property to exclude files and directories from backups (See [Technical Q&A QA1719](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html)). If you want to use the default path, there is the only way to exclude Realm file from backups.

```
let realm = Realm()
if let realmPathURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: realm.path) {
    realmPathURL.setResourceValue(NSNumber(bool: true), forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey, error: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Finally I did what you said by setting the defaultPath to <Application_Data>/Library/Caches according to [link](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:ZvC10RealmSwift5Realm11defaultPathSS)

Comment: kishikawa-san This will tell icloud not to backup `data.realm`. How about other files like `default.realm.lock`, `default.realm.management/`, `default.realm.note` ? Do we need to set the resource value there too?

Comment: @nacho4d Typically set the attribute to a directory that includes realm and auxiliary files. But the attribute is set `true` by default at v2.10.1. You do not need to do it yourself. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/5270

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the URL API has changed since the previous answer was posted. This is how you can disable the backup now:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
guard var url = realm.configuration.fileURL else {
    return
}
var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
resourceValues.isExcludedFromBackup = true
try? url.setResourceValues(resourceValues)
```